# Código VBA para inserir imagens no excel não consegue reconhecer imagens que possuem letras e caracteres especiais no nome da imagem

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Utilizo o seguinte código VBA para pegar imagens de uma pasta e inserir em uma planilha, porém  o código VBA não consegue reconhecer imagens que possuem letras e caracteres especiais no nome da imagem, ex: (SP20-TP02), se o nome da imagem for apenas número (2020), funciona perfeitamente, segue o código:

```
Public Function getImage(ByVal sCode As String) As String

    Dim sFile As String
    Dim oSheet As Worksheet
    Dim oCell As Range
    Dim oImage As Shape

    Set oCell = Application.Caller ' Célula onde a função foi chamada
    Set oSheet = oCell.Parent      ' Planilha que chamou a função

    ' Procura por uma imagem existente identificada pelo código (que precisa ser único!)
    Set oImage = Nothing
    For i = 1 To oSheet.Shapes.Count
        If oSheet.Shapes(i).Name = sCode Then
            Set oImage = oSheet.Shapes(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i


    ' Se ainda não existir uma imagem com o código, carrega do arquivo e cria-a.
    ' A imagem já é posicionada na exata posição da célula onde a função foi chamada.
    If oImage Is Nothing Then
        sFile = "C:\macro\" & sCode & ".jpg"
        Set oImage = oSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(sFile, msoCTrue, msoCTrue, oCell.Left, oCell.Top, oCell.Width, oCell.Height)
        oImage.Name = sCode

    ' Caso contrário, se a imagem já existir, garante que ela se posiciona e cabe exatamente dentro da célula
    ' (apenas para o caso do usuário ter movido ou redimensionado manualmente a imagem sem querer)
    Else
        With oImage
            .Left = oCell.Left
            .Top = oCell.Top
            .Width = oCell.Width
            .Height = oCell.Height
        End With
    End If

    ' Retorna nada para a célula (afinal, esta é somente uma função de auxílio)
    getImage = ""

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema da sua função é que ao inserir: `=getImage(SP20-TP02)` o Excel converte SP20-TP02 para SP20-TP2 e entende como um range de células da coluna SP e linha 20 até a coluna TP linha 2, que se estiverem vazias retorna 0.

Uma maneira de verificar isto é inserir o código `MsgBox "'" & sCode & "'"`, que retornará como a função está entendendo a String inserida dentro dela.

### Solução

#### 1 - Converter o valor desejado para formato String com: `=TEXTO("SP20-TP02";"@")`

Então a fórmula fica: `=getImage(TEXTO("SP20-TP02";"@"))`

#### 2 - Inserir o valor numa célula e referenciar na UDF

Se por exemplo o código desejado é inserido na célula B1, a fórmula fica: `=getImage(B1)`

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!!!